# Running a python script in a discord javascript coded bot

Tags: javascript, python, discord, bots

How can I run a Python script inside a JavaScript Discord Bot code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant just interpret python code in javascript. You could try to spawn a proccess and execute your python script and take the output.
Here is a solution, how to do this: [node.js call external exe and wait for output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34538825/node-js-call-external-exe-and-wait-for-output/34539036)

Comment: I meant that I want to run a Python script calling it from a JavaScript code.

Comment: Like i already said with my first sentence, you cant just interprete Python Code in Javascript. How this should work?